# Check If All Tags Are Closed

Tags: html

I have a large dynamic website that is being constructed by PHP. I suspect that one of my components are not closing the HTML tags properly. I have the source output HTML. I am wondering if there is a script, or website, that will tell me if all my tags are closed and such?

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/, for a start?

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/ should work.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/ it validates your output

Comment: Well, guess I won't post that as an answer then.

Comment: Rofl. Thank you. Totally forgot about that.

Comment: Is there any JavaScript library for this, So we don't need to make ajax call ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the W3C Markup Validator Service at http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thanks. Totally forgot about  that service.

Answer (score 2):

Just for interest, I shall point out that [validator.nu](http://validator.nu/) is better for checking HTML4 than the W3C validator. Suppose your markup is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
                 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="Test" /
    <title>Test Case</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `<meta>` element clearly isn't closed where it should be, and the result is that the `<title>` element won't be recognised in browsers.

But give that markup to the W3C validator and it will tell you that it validates. That's because it is based on SGML processing which permits a syntax known a Null End Tag (NET) syntax, which makes it think that the `/` ends the tag.

Browsers do not support NET syntax, and neither does validator.nu, thus correctly flagging the markup as in error.

For HTML5, both validators are good.

Comment: Is there any JavaScript library for this, So we don't need to make ajax call ?

Answer (score 1):

Try HTML Tidy.  Theres a firefox plugin version as well

If you work alot in your browser and dont want to jump back and forth to the w3 schools this is a good choice, but like everyone who commented said, the validator is good as well.

Answer (score -2):

[This Website](https://www.aliciaramirez.com/closing-tags-checker/) checks if there are unclosed tags, and tells you which ones are not closed, and the line they belong